# Notation for many-sorted term algebras

Tags: universal-algebra

I'm writing a computer science paper, and need to give a formal definition of many-sorted term algebras (which correspond to the abstract syntax of programming languages). I'm having trouble finding a standard development of the theory to use.

So far, I've been giving my own notation for use in the rest of the paper, using the definitions from the book *Term Rewriting and All That* as a starting point and doing the straightforward generalization to the many-sorted case. However, I suspect I've used a name incorrectly at some point, and really would like to have an existing set of definitions to work with. Anyone know one?

Comment: In the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818537/is-there-a-generalization-of-universal-algebras-that-allows-the-use-of-multiple) there is a link to a paper which presents an introduction to the topic focusing on the differences between one-sorted and many-sorted algebraic treatment. Maybe that paper and its references could be helpful to you too.

Comment: Skimming through now.

"as
A (many-sorted) signature is a pair Σ = S, Ω, where:
• S is a set (of sort names); and
• Ω is an (S ∗ × S )-sorted set (of operation names)"

Already much clearer than my exposition. Thank you!